# Assigning values to zip codes

Tags: java, android

What I am trying to do is assign a number value to a group of zip codes and then use that number to do a calculation later on in the program. What I have now is

```
if (zip == 93726 || zip == 93725 || zip == 92144) {
    return 100;
  }

else if (zip == 94550 || zip == 34599 || zip == 77375) {
    return 150;
  }
```

and then I take the variable and use it in a calculation. Assigning the number to the variable and the calculation all work but what I have ran into is apparently android only allows you to have so many lines of code and I have ran out of lines with just using if else statements. My question is what would be a better what to go about this?

I am not trying to assign a city to each zip because I have seen that they have services that do that from other posters.

Comment: Have a database table with the zip code in one column and the value in another column.

Comment: "apparently android only allows you to have so many lines of code and I have ran out of lines with just using if else statements." Where did you find that?

Comment: StephaneM when I went to emulate the program in Android Studio it told me that I ran out of space.

Comment: Zipcodes should not be handled as integers. You should use `String`.

Comment: What is the smallest and largest return value?

Answer (score 1):

a. You can either use a

```
switch (zip)
{
case 93726: case 93725: case 92144: return 100;
case 94550: case 34599: case 77375: return 150;
}
```

-

b. or create a `HashMap<Integer,Integer>` and fill it with 'zip to value' entries, which should give you a much better performance if you have that many cases.

```
Map<Integer,Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
m.put(93726,100);
```

later you could call

```
return m.get(zip);
```

-

c. If your zip count is in the tens of thousands and you want to work all in memory, then you should consider just holding a hundred-thousand int sized array:

```
int[] arr=new int[100000];
```

and filling it with the data:

```
arr[93726]=100;
.
.
.
```

Comment: Note that using `if/else` or `case` has poor performance `O(n)` and a HashMap would perform better `O(1)` but is likely to go out of memory. I think a disk based solution with an index is better (ie a database)

Comment: HashMap is O(1) with high probability.

Comment: Oops... you're right... HashMap is O(1) and TreeMap is O(log(n))

Answer (score 1):

1. You should *probably* use String constants for you ZIP codes since

   - in some places, some start with 0
   - in some places, they may contain letters as well as numbers
2. If you are using an `Object` (either `String` or `Integer`) for your constants, I have often used `Collection.contains(zip)` as a lazy shortcut for the condition in each if statement. That collection contains all the constants for that condition, and you would probably use a subclass that is geared towards finding, perhaps `HashSet`. Keep in mind that if you use a `HashMap` solution as suggested elsewhere, your keys will be `Integer` objects too, so you will do hashing on the keys in any case, you just won't need to store the result values in the collection suggestion.

   I suspect that for a large collection of constants, hashing may turn out to be faster than having to work through the large number of `==` conditions in the `if` statement until you get to the right condition. (It may help a bit if the most-used constants come first, and in the first `if` statement...)

On a completely different note (i.e. strategy instead of code), you should see if you could group your ZIPs. What I mean is for example, that if you know that **all (or most)** ZIPs of the forms "923xx" and "924xx" result in a return of 250, you could potentially shorten your conditionals considerably. E.g. `zip.startsWith("923") || zip.startsWith("923")` for `String` ZIPs, or `(zip / 100) == 923 || (zip / 100) == 924` for `int`.

A small number of more specific exceptions to the groups can still be handled, you just need to have the more specific conditionals before the more general conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

Use declarative data. Especially as the zip codes might get updated, extended, corrected:

Using for instance a zip.properties

```
points = 100, 150

zip100 = 93726, 93725, 92144
zip150 = 94550, 34599, 77375,\
         88123, 12324, 23424
```

And

```
Map<Integer, Integer> zipToPoints = new HashMap<>();
```

If you got ZIP codes with leading zeroes maybe better use String or take care to parse them with base 10 (leading zero is base 8, octal).

Whether there really exists such a limitation I do not know, but the extra effort of a bit of coding is worth having all as data.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `Map` which maps each zip code to an integer. For example:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> zipCodeMap = new HashMap<>();
zipCodeMap.put(93726, 100);
```

And later you can retrieve values from there.

```
Integer value = zipCodeMap.get(93726);
```

Now you still have to map each zipcode to a value. I would not do that in Java code but rather use a database or read from a text file (csv for example). This depends mostly on your requirements.

---

Example csv file:

```
93726, 100
93727, 100
93726, 150
```

Reading from a csv file:

```
InputStream is = this.class.getResourceAsStream("/data.csv");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
try {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] row = line.split(",");
        int zip = Integer.parseInt(row[0].trim());
        int value = Integer.parseInt(row[1].trim());
        zipCodeMap.put(zip, value);
    }
}
catch (IOException ex) {
    // handle exceptions here
}
finally {
    try {
        is.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // handle exceptions here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a map of the zip codes.just return the value.

```
Map<Integer,Integer> zipValues = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
zipValues.put(93726,100);
```

.
.
And so on. or u can read from a prop file and populate the map.

then instead of using the if(s),

```
 return zipValues.get(zipCode);
```

so say zipCode=93726, it will return u 100.

Cheers.